# Como colocar EditText ao lado de Edit Text dinâmicamente?

Tags: android

Estou criando um formulário dinâmico e precisava exibir em um formulário, Idade e Endereço na mesma linha. Eu criei um "for" para criar n vezes o mesmo formulário mas está dando erro. segue o código:

```
public void form() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Nome");
        layout.addView(tv);
        EditText et = new EditText(this);
        et.setText("");
        layout.addView(et);

        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText("Idade");
        layout2.addView(tv1);
        EditText et1 = new EditText(this);
        et1.setText("");
        layout2.addView(et1);

        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setText("Endereco");
        layout2.addView(tv2);
        EditText et2 = new EditText(this);
        et2.setText("");
        layout2.addView(et2);
        // AQUI COLOCO O LAYOUT HORIZONTAL DENTRO DO VERTICAL, FUNCIONA A LÓGICA, PORÈM ESTÁ DANDO ERRO POR CAUSA DO FOR
        layout.addView(layout2);

        TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
        tv3.setText("Telefone");
        layout.addView(tv3);
        EditText et3 = new EditText(this);
        et3.setText("");
        layout.addView(et3);

    }

}
```

Obs: layout -> LinearLayout vertical
     layout2 - > LinearLayout horizontal.

Se eu tirar o "for" do código, ele  funciona, mas eu preciso usar o "for". Alguém pode dar uma ajuda. Agradeço desde já!!!

Comment: Não seria pelo fato de que você esta criando os campos com os mesmos nomes?
Por Ex, se você tirar esse for e pegar esses Texts e copiar e colar três vezes ele irá apresentar erro né? Tem como mostrar a mensagem de erro?

Comment: é exatamente esta a mensagem de erro, será que tem algum jeito de manter o for. Porque se eu tirar o "layout.addView(layout2);" funciona mesmo com o for.

Answer (score 1):

Uma view não pode ser adicionada 2 vezes dentro de outra view. Tu tem que tornar a criação de **layout2** dinâmica.

Para fazer isso tu pode criar essa view em um xml separado e **inflar** cada vez que quiser uma nova instância.